# havingPredicate with NSExpressionDescription property

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to produce a fetch request which does what this SQL statement does:

```
SELECT contact, min(date) as minDate FROM sales group by contact HAVING minDate >= *startDate* && minDate <= *endDate*
```

This should return a list of new customers in the period between startDate and endDate.
But I can't seem to convert it into a NSFetchRequest.

```
NSExpressionDescription* minDate = ..expression for key 'date', function min:
minDate.name = @"minDate";
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"contact", minDate];
fetchRequest.havingPredicate = [NSPredicateWithFormat:@"minDate >=%@ and minDate <= %@", self.start, self.end];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"contact"];
```

When executing this request, I get a runtime error, stating that keyPath minDate not found in entity.

How should I do it then ?

Comment: It might be less efficient but if you don't set the `havingPredicate` and use the regular `date` property in your predicate won't that give you the same results?

Comment: Not really. I want it to go through all the dates, find the minimum date for each contact and then, check if the minimum date is within the range. If I use the predicate on the date, it will first get the dates in range, then find the minimum date, which is not what I want.